# Замена с помощью preg_replace

Tags: замена, preg_replace

Как из `[url=http://site]name[/url]` сделать `<a href="http://site">name</a>` с помощь `preg_replace`?

Comment: @недекWHAT, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo preg_replace(
    "~\[url=((?:ftp|https?)://.+?)\](.+?)\[/url\]~", 
    '<a href="\\1">\\2</a>', 
    "[url=ftp://site]name[/url][url=https://site]name[/url]"
);
```